# Querying by attribute in Riak

Tags: java, nosql, riak

I'm developing an app with Riak and java. Basically I want to store news, for which I have an object with this attributes:

```
public String title;
public String author;
public String URL;
public ArrayList<String> categories;
public String description;
public String release;
```

It's working properly but now I want to allow users to search for news by keywords.

The problem is that I only find in the java client documentation queries by primary key, which are done like this:

```
    RiakClient client = RiakClient.newClient(10017, "127.0.0.1");
    Location location = new Location(new 
    Namespace("TestBucket"),"TestKey");

    FetchValue fv = new FetchValue.Builder(location).build();
    FetchValue.Response response = client.execute(fv);

    // Fetch object as String
    String value = response.getValue(String.class);
    System.out.println(value);

    client.shutdown();
```

Is there a way to query by attributes? For example, could you search if a word is in the title?

Because right now the only option I see is to get all the objects from the database and search by hand, which seems very inefficient to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there two ways to query things by attributes, either using secondary indexes (so called 2i), or by using Riak Search. I suggest you start by using secondary index, it's easy enough. Basically when you write data, you need to decide which attribute you want to be indexed. Then you can query these indexes. They can be numeric or alphanumeric, and you can query ranges.

See https://docs.riak.com/riak/kv/latest/using/reference/secondary-indexes/index.html
And example using 2i with HTTP API: https://docs.riak.com/riak/kv/latest/developing/api/http/secondary-indexes/index.html

Check out the doc of the java client you're using.